# mod_rewrite not Working in grabkart.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Have My Own Website grabkart

`Grabkart.com` is online shopping portle

I want To make Change url of my website from

```
http://www.grabkart.com/productdetail.php?prodid=4385
```

to

```
http://www.grabkart.com/productdetail/4385
```

What Change I Have to make in my.htaccess file for this

Comment: Are you using an app like magento, prestashop, opencart or similar? Can you change the links of your pages to look like what you mentioned or you cant `http://www.grabkart.com/productdetail/4385` if you can then its a simple htaccess rule if you can't its slight more complicated?

Comment: ya I tried Lot More thing But I can't I hosted grabkart on godaddy server I take multiple hosting facelity in my hosting accout root folder consist another website

Comment: No, I am asking if you can change on your HTML the links to that, if you can 1 htaccess rule will solve your problem.

Comment: See bastien's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^productdetail/([0-9]+)/?$     productdetail.php?prodid=$1
```

Comment: No Not syntex Error Here is my.htaccess file# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^productdetail/([0-9]+)/?$ productdetail.php?prodid=$1

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Place the above in your .htacces, and assuming you have full admin rights on your server, and can access the hidden files - this should work.

In the above code the -d stands for Directory and -f for Regular File.
and the above will remove the .php extension from your URLs.
For example, if your page name is test.php in the main directory then you may access your page with the following urls: 
grabkart/test 
or
 grabkart/test.php. 
This will works in both conditions, and the same logic can be applied to anything you would like removing from the path.

Comment: I wrote This code not working see http://www.grabkart.com/index.php

Comment: Try Bastien's answer, mine was written from memory.  There may be a syntax error!

Comment: No Not Syntex error here is my .htaccess file# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^productdetail/([0-9]+)/?$ productdetail.php?prodid=$1

Comment: I have no way of testing to see if this is correct or not, have you ensured the .htaccess is formatted correctly?

How did you create it?

The first time I created one it was called .htaccess.txt :p

Comment: Ok I Do It But Now I Can see That My Product detail page Loads but It Loads without Css Why

Comment: Without seeing the code, I couldn't tell you.  Syntax error in the HTML?